# Saved image takes minutes to appear in Gallery

Tags: android

I'm saving a bitmap in the SD card and I called the `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED` right after.

It displays in the Gallery but it takes about 5 minutes for the image to appear. Is there any way to make it instantaneous?

```
File newFile = new File(newFilename);
if (newFile.exists()) { 
    newFile.delete();
}

try {
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
   out.flush();
   out.close();
   context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
   Toast.makeText(context, "Photo will appear in the Gallery in a few minutes.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass your file to a MediaScannerConnection : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html .
That way the system can instantly knows that there is a new file that needs to be added to the Gallery.
Right now, you have to wait until the system scans the filesystem and see your file, which of course is not instantaneous.
And by the way, when you will have implemented this, you should be able to remove the Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED call, it is not here to broadcast file additions (MediaScannerConnection is).

Answer (score 0):

```
We can use this way also

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent resultData) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);

        Log.v(TAG + ".onActivityResult", "onActivityResult");


         if (resultData != null) {

                Uri selectedImage = resultData.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);

                uploadImagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                bitmapUploadImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uploadImagePath);

                cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firing the ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED intent is scanning the entire SD card which is probably why you're seeing such a delay.  Take a look at MediaScannerConnection.scan [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html).  Using the MediaScannerConnection you can add individual files, and receive notification when they have been added.